# How to make an image ignore the size of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm going to try to explain what I want to do with screenshots.

This is how my website looks right now, screen size 1920x1080:

https://gyazo.com/95cc6f61a449f67fb00232a7619a58d7

This is how I want my website to look:

gyazo.com/c5cf33080a04f0d3d9b5b0252f013ba3

BUT! I don't want the logo to resize itself, I want it to remain the the relative position of the shape it's on after it got resized.

Practically, I want the shape to remain the same size regardless of resolution, how do I do this?

I tried editing the CSS and using the 100%/auto trick but it's not what I want to do.

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58241.html is what I'm trying to replicate in my example. (THIS IS ALL FOR LEARNING PURPOSES)

Try zooming in or out on that page and you'll see the shape is keeping it's form regardless of zoom level.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to supply a MCVE for us to be able to help with your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the logo from resizing you need to set fixed width and height with a pixel value. Ex: 150px. That should keep it from resizing itself.
Keep in mind that to replicate that example, you need to involve the original logo with a responsive element.